# Help Text on a Configuration Attribute in CPQ Line Editor

Tags: configuration, quote, cpq, quotelineitem, helptext

I am trying to accomplish what I think would be a simple task. Is it possible to add help text of some sort to a configuration attribute in the line editor of Salesforce CPQ?